# R special data frame

Tags: r, xts, random-forest

I'm asking a question follwing the one I asked yesterday in this post : [Random Forests for Variables selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584704/r-rolling-random-forest-for-variables-selection).

I managed to find out for each quarter the most significant technical trading rules. I've built a data frame to put the names of these TTR. Here is it, I've got with one column for quarter.

```
              1       2     3      4       5     6     7       8       9      10           11
1          RSI2    RSI3  RSI2  RSI10    RSI2  RSI2  RSI2    RSI2    RSI2    RSI2         RSI2
2          RSI3    RSI4  RSI3  RSI20    RSI3  RSI3  RSI3    RSI4    RSI4    RSI3         RSI3
3          RSI4    RSI5  RSI4   EMA5    RSI4  RSI4  RSI5    RSI5    RSI5    RSI4         RSI4
4          RSI5   RSI10  RSI5  EMA20    RSI5  RSI5 RSI10    EMA5   RSI10    RSI5         RSI5
5         RSI10   RSI20 RSI10  EMA60    SMA5 RSI10 RSI20   EMA20   RSI20   RSI10        RSI10
6         SMA20   SMA60 RSI20    SMI     atr RSI20 SMA60   EMA60    SMA5   RSI20         SMA5
7         SMA60    pctB SMA20    ADX    pctB  EMA5   atr     atr   SMA60     atr        SMA20
8           atr calcs.1  pctB   pctB    macd EMA20  pctB     ADX    pctB     ADX        EMA20
9          pctB    <NA>  <NA>   macd myVolat EMA60  <NA>    pctB    macd    pctB        EMA60
10 myChaikinVol    <NA>  <NA> signal calcs.1  pctB  <NA>    macd  signal myVolat          ADX
11      myVolat    <NA>  <NA>  calcs    <NA>  macd  <NA>  signal   mySAR calcs.1         pctB
12        calcs    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA> myVolat myVolat    <NA> myChaikinVol
13         <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA> calcs.1    <NA>    <NA>      myVolat
14         <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        calcs
```

I've added `NA`to cope with the differing length of rows.

Now, I would like to come back to my dataset which looks like that :

```
           daily.returns      RSI2     RSI3     RSI4     RSI5    RSI10    RSI20     SMA5    SMA20    SMA60     EMA5    EMA20    EMA60      atr      SMI      ADX oscillator        pctB      macd       signal myChaikinVol    mySAR   myVolat     calcs   calcs.1
2009-01-07  -0.015587635 97.964071 92.62210 87.21605 82.40040 66.95642 55.19221 19720.64 18655.29 17758.68 2556.777 2556.777 2556.777 82.06602 27.52145 17.31637         85  0.87092366 0.5930649 -0.220581024   -0.3211637 2369.876 0.2325009 0.3169638 0.2801128
2009-01-08  -0.008700162 43.766573 58.62387 62.97794 64.03382 60.23197 52.99739 19756.44 18666.60 17754.07 2566.499 2566.499 2566.499 80.33416 29.12141 16.86914         85  0.72197937 0.8929854  0.002132269   -0.3183377 2385.210 0.2201065 0.3169831 0.2654092
2009-01-09  -0.011980596 27.182247 44.97072 52.29336 55.50633 56.74068 51.80171 19776.92 18674.31 17750.34 2523.372 2523.372 2523.372 78.65886 29.37878 15.90677         85  0.67025741 0.9349831  0.188702427   -0.2613410 2403.582 0.2245705 0.3119865 0.2608195
2009-01-12  -0.014061295 13.371347 30.46561 39.97055 45.24210 52.16207 50.17764 19788.02 18683.05 17748.76 2524.466 2524.466 2524.466 78.58966 28.17871 14.80066         85  0.49082443 0.9958785  0.350137644   -0.2065359 2420.117 0.2217528 0.3128203 0.2615878
2009-01-13  -0.016693272  6.141462 19.52298 29.30404 35.68593 47.25383 48.32987 19772.25 18693.01 17749.35 2488.165 2488.165 2488.165 76.08326 25.34705 13.96936         80  0.26923307 0.8855971  0.457229531   -0.1845331 2434.998 0.2223591 0.3103439 0.2609330
2009-01-14  -0.047918393  2.712386 11.97834 20.69541 27.26891 42.10718 46.23469 19747.87 18694.16 17742.88 2449.353 2449.353 2449.353 75.42231 20.65686 13.99099         60 -0.01023467 0.6624063  0.498264880   -0.1131268 2445.040 0.2290943 0.3094655 0.2644883
```

What I would like to do is put an `NA`during the periods when a TTR is not significant. For example if the RSI2 TTR turns out not to be significant during the first quarter I would like to replace the numerical values by `NA`s , but if the RSI2 is significant during the 5th quarter I would like to keep the numerical values.

At the end, I should get a data frame which dimensions are the same as the intial data frame.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post your code.  Instead of a `data.frame`, try storing a `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be storing your rules in a list, rather than a data.frame.  This saves your from having to pad each "rule list" with NAs to make them the same length, and also allows you to process your data with `lapply`.

Since you didn't provide any data, I made some up:

```
#Load data
set.seed(42)
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('SPY')
SPY <- adjustOHLC(SPY)
dat <- dailyReturn(Cl(SPY))

#Add some TTRs
for (rule in c('RSI', 'SMA')){
  for (n in c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)){
    newvar <- paste(rule, n, sep='_')
    FUN <- get(rule)
    dat <- cbind(dat, FUN(dat[,1], n=n))
    names(dat)[length(names(dat))] <- newvar
  }
}
dat <- na.omit(dat)
rulenames <- names(dat)[-1]
```

Note that this is an `xts` object, not a data.frame.  This is important, as it keeps the index in the `Date` format, rather than as a character vector:

```
> dat[1:5, 1:5]
           daily.returns    RSI_5   RSI_10   RSI_15   RSI_20
2007-02-08  -0.001308450 40.06379 46.99824 48.59484 49.11738
2007-02-09  -0.007447249 26.65296 40.34267 44.35689 46.10753
2007-02-12  -0.003404196 42.49883 45.94447 47.58264 48.30373
2007-02-13   0.008434995 67.89045 58.59450 55.64932 54.07276
2007-02-14   0.006567123 62.45177 56.28547 54.23836 53.08886
```

I also made up some TTRs to use for each year

```
#Make a list of rules for each year
library(lubridate)
dat$Year <- year(index(dat))
uniqueYear <- sort(unique(dat$Year))
rulesList <- lapply(uniqueYear, function(x) rulenames[runif(length(rulenames))>.5])
names(rulesList) <- uniqueYear
```

Note that my ruleList is literally a list:

```
> rulesList
$`2007`
[1] "RSI_5"  "RSI_10" "RSI_20" "RSI_25" "SMA_5"  "SMA_10" "SMA_20" "SMA_25"

$`2008`
[1] "RSI_10" "RSI_15" "SMA_5"  "SMA_10" "SMA_25"

$`2009`
[1] "RSI_5"  "RSI_15" "RSI_20" "SMA_5"  "SMA_15" "SMA_25"

$`2010`
[1] "RSI_5"  "RSI_10" "RSI_20" "SMA_5"  "SMA_20" "SMA_25"

$`2011`
[1] "RSI_20" "SMA_5"  "SMA_10" "SMA_15" "SMA_20" "SMA_25"

$`2012`
[1] "RSI_20" "SMA_5"  "SMA_10" "SMA_25"
```

Now it's simply a matter of looping through each year, and subsetting the `dat` object to the proper rows (year) and columns (TTRs):

```
#Apply the rules to each data.frame
data.by.year <- lapply(uniqueYear, function(year){
  rule_subset <- rulesList[[as.character(year)]]
  data_subset <- dat[dat$Year==year, rule_subset]
})
names(data.by.year) <- uniqueYear
```

The `data.by.year` is a list (of length 6), where each element represent 1 year's worth of data, with the selected TTRs.

```
> str(data.by.year[[1]])
An ‘xts’ object from 2007-02-08 to 2007-12-31 containing:
  Data: num [1:226, 1:8] 40.1 26.7 42.5 67.9 62.5 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:8] "RSI_5" "RSI_10" "RSI_20" "RSI_25" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 3
 $ tclass   : chr "Date"
 $ tzone    : chr ""
 $ na.action:Class 'omit'  atomic [1:25] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "index")= num [1:25] 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 ...
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zach for your very valuable answer.